# How to return to top of code? Maybe?

Tags: java, if-statement, int

I am extremely new to programming Java and have what I'm sure is a very easy fix.  I have the following code, and it works, but I was wondering how I could change it so if the user inputs something other than an int, it would loop back to the top after it gives the error message, so it would ask for a temp again.  Thanks in advance.

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    //User input of temperature
    System.out.print("Enter temperature in Celsius: ");
    if (in.hasNextInt())
    {
        int temperature = in.nextInt();
        //Now determine what state the water will be in, either ice, gas, or water.
        if (temperature >=100)
        {
            System.out.print("Gas!");
        }
        else if ((temperature <100) && (temperature >0))
        {
            System.out.print("Water!");
        }
        else if (temperature <=0)
        {
            System.out.print("Ice!");
        }
    }
    else
    {
         System.out.println("Error: Not an Integer");
         System.out.print("Please enter temperature in Celsius: ");
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

move it into a method

```
public static void main( String args[] ){

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    readInput( in );
}

public static void readInput( Scanner in ){

    System.out.print("Enter temperature in Celsius: "); 
    if ( in.hasNextInt() ){
        // do your stuff here
    }
    else {
        // print the errors
        readInput( in );
    }
}
```

Comment: Your method is definitely more sophisticated than mine. +1.

Comment: @simchona, they are equivalent, but this way is probably more readable; but one could (and actually should) just as well put the while loop into a new method

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you should look into using a `while()` loop. You can use a snippet [like this](http://learnaboutandroid.blogspot.com/2011/06/lesson-three-loops-and-scanners.html):

> ```
> Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
> int input = -1; 
> input = scanner.nextInt();
> while (input != 0)
> {
>  System.out.println("Enter 0 to exit the loop.");
>  input = scanner.nextInt(); //without this, you will hit a loop that never ends. 
> {
> ```

Where you can add your code to convert the temperature within that loop.

Comment: this is a nice example where `do ... while` is appropriate so you don't need to write `input = scanner.nextInt();` twice

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the [while loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a loop. Look here for an introduction:
http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/flow/loops/loops.html

Answer (score 0):

wrap your code with a loop, I would use while(...) for this purpose, exit condition would be an 'int' input.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html

To validate user input use eg. regexp something like this:
userInput.matches("[-+]?\d+(\.\d+)?");

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solution to your answer is to stick your code into an infinite "run" loop.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true) {
    //User input of temperature
    System.out.print("Enter temperature in Celsius: ");
    if (in.hasNextInt())
    {
        int temperature = in.nextInt();
        //Now determine what state the water will be in, either ice, gas, or water.
        if (temperature >=100)
        {
            System.out.print("Gas!");
        }
        else if ((temperature <100) && (temperature >0))
        {
            System.out.print("Water!");
        }
        else if (temperature <=0)
        {
            System.out.print("Ice!");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Error: Not an Integer");
        System.out.print("Please enter temperature in Celsius: ");
    }
}
```

[Run loops](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop), or main loops as they're often called, provide a consistent loop that accepts user input and provides feedback. If/when you get into multi-threading/GUI programming, this is where most of your UI code goes. However, most project-based environments (Eclipse for Android apps, Xcode for iOS apps, etc.) have more complex and idiomatic run loops than `while (true)`.

Comment: should probably leave the `Scanner in = new Scanner( System. in );` out of the loop

Comment: I actually went with this method, since I got a million errors when I tried the first (I'm probably doing something wrong with it as I said, I am extremely new).  I added a break; after all of the if/else if's and it works fine up there, but if I type in letters for example and it goes to the else statement, it non stop loops saying "Enter temperature in Celsius: Error: Not an Integer Please enter temperature in Celsius:".  So I guess now I am trying to figure out how to take it from the else back to the top, and stop there, waiting for another user input